# kerberos ticket not renewable

Tags: centos, kerberos

I followed all recommended MIT kerberos configuration settings. I created a principal and when I do kadmin.local getprinc I see the following

```
kadmin.local:  getprinc centos@HADOOP.PSM
Principal: centos@HADOOP.PSM
Expiration date: [never]
Last password change: Sun Mar 13 07:55:56 UTC 2016
Password expiration date: [none]
Maximum ticket life: 1 day 00:00:00
Maximum renewable life: 10 days 00:00:00
Last modified: Sun Mar 13 07:55:56 UTC 2016 (root/admin@HADOOP.PSM)
Last successful authentication: [never]
Last failed authentication: [never]
```

When I do a `kinit` and then `klist`, I see the following (which is wrong because I don't see a `renew until mm:dd:yy` date in the response

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: centos@HADOOP.PSM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
03/13/2016 07:56:21  03/14/2016 07:56:19  krbtgt/HADOOP.PSM@HADOOP.PSM
```

When a renewal request is made, then I see this in the logs

```
TGS_REQ (1 etypes {23}) 10.0.0.10: TICKET NOT RENEWABLE: authtime 0,  centos@HADOOP.PSM for krbtgt/HADOOP.PSM@HADOOP.PSM, KDC can't fulfill requested option
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the Service Principal had a maximum renewal life of 0 days. Maybe I created that before making the conf changes..!

So this is the culprit `krbtgt/HADOOP.PSM@HADOOP.PSM`

When I modified the service principal like below, it worked..!

```
modprinc -maxlife 1days -maxrenewlife 7days +allow_renewable krbtgt/HADOOP.PSM@HADOOP.PSM
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Something changed in my own domain where my tickets expired after 24h.  I assume they must have been renewing before.  I hadn't modified any of my principals so expect it was due to an upgrade.  Modifying my krbtgt/REALM@REALM principal as you showed did the trick!